# load data in computed properties

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember component which represents a purchase form. You can create old purchase payed in other currency. The converted amount of the purchase depends on the currency chosen and the date of the purchase. So the converted amount is my computed property. The source of the exchange rates is a model backended by an external web service through a custom adapter and they are retrieved by date. This means that when the date changes in the form I may need to call the service. All this happen in the computed property but I know that loading data in it in not a best practice, so I wonder what alternatives I have.

Comment: you can try by firing some action from the date input field on change event, and you can then execute the code from service and update the amount property after your service returns the data from server. This way you won't need to trigger a call to service from a computed.property. This is just one of the way. If a better solution is required, please place in some code about how you are doing it. This would help other community members to suggest possible better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to follow Data Down Actions Up principle, meaning you are not supposed to have logic related to your data in components. You are supposed to send actions from component to controller, handle data related things in the controller and then data is passed back to the component through component's parameter.

Saying that myself I sometimes break this rule if I feel that data handling is conceptually related to a component and the component is going to be reused. I would better encapsulate it in the component in this case.

If you need a more specific answer, please post your code.